# Datastore Filter doesn't work in Google App Engine with java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud

I have a problem with retrieving data from data store.

Here is a sample of an Entity stored on the data store:
[image]

I am using GAE with java, and I managed to store data in the data store, but now I need to fetch the stored data using `DatastoreService()` and `Filter()`.

The problem is that even when I enter the right values in the WHERE clause, there is no data !!

```
DatastoreService dataStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Filter usernameFilter = new FilterPredicate("Name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "moha");

Query q = new Query("User").setFilter(usernameFilter);
PreparedQuery pq = dataStore.prepare(q);

pq.countEntities() //returns 0 always
```

I have even tried to use the online "Query by GQL" and still no data:

```
select * from User where Name = 'moha'
```

Here is the entity code:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The ID/Name you see in the datastore viewer is in the Key and is not a property of the entity such as 'Name'.

You should include you model and how you created the entity.

Your select query will be for **key** not Name.

The simplest way to prove this is get the enrity by it's key which you can see above.

Comment: So you can see from the your code you aren't defining a property called "Name" you are confusing properties with elements of the key

Comment: So it wouldn't help when I use "username" though ?

Comment: What is stored in the 'username' property ?  You should be able to see that it tne datastore viewer. If you have a value you can query for that .I don't use Java, but this looks wrong FilterPredicate("Name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "moha") is your trying to filter on Username.